# In an addin is there a way to hide the toolbar (Add new item) of a list view webpart withing the xml definition?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm using the following code to show a list to a page and i want to hide the Add New Item button

```
<File Path="Pages\MyLeaveRequests.aspx" Url="Pages/MyLeaveRequests.aspx" ReplaceContent="TRUE">

  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="myLeaveRequestID" WebPartOrder="1">
    <![CDATA[
<webParts>
<webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, 
                   Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="ListUrl">Lists/LeaveRequest</property>
        <property name="IsIncluded">True</property>
        <property name="NoDefaultStyle">True</property>
        <property name="Title">My Leave Requests</property>
        <property name="PageType">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
        <property name="Default">False</property>
        <property name="ShowToolbarWithRibbon" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ViewContentTypeId">2x</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
    </webParts>
  ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
```

How can i do this within the xml definition ? Should i just use javascript to hide it ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the list directly on the web page.  This works for both libraries and lists.

1. Edit the page.
2. Edit the web part.
3. Change the Toolbar Type from Full Toolbar to No Toolbar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is part of an addin. It should have the button remove as the page opens.

Comment: After updating the web part settings once, you never have to do it again for that web page.  That being said, in the web part code you provided, what happens if you remove  "<property name="ShowToolbarWithRibbon" type="bool">False</property>"?

Comment: If i remove it , it still shows the button. The only way i found to remove it is to change the css for that class on that page :  <style type="text/css">
        .ms-addnew {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>